# Settings fence posts above bottom of hole?

Tags: fence

When setting post in hole, should you put it a small brick or mixed concrete in the botoom before setting post?

Comment: you did not say what material the post is made from .... put concrete in bottom of hole so that the post does not touch dirt

Comment: I usually add gravel so there will be room for water to drain if I use anything other than concrete.